# Unable to connect 4G/LTE Modem. ModemManager shuts off as soon as it tries to connect

Tags: 18.04, usb-modem, modem-manager, 4g

When I run `ModemManager --debug` on the terminal, I get [this output](https://pastebin.com/pR0CRzQi).

Running `mmcli -L` gives me:

```
/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [huawei] E3372
```

And running `mmcli -m 0` gives me [this output](https://pastebin.com/72aVjYcC).

When I try to start modemmanager by `sudo /usr/sbin/ModemManager`, I get:

```
ModemManager[9099]: <info> ModemManager (version 1.10.0) starting in system bus...
ModemManager[9099]: <warn> Could not acquire the 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager1' service name
ModemManager[9099]: <info> ModemManager is shut down
```

I've been trying all the solutions on Google but to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated!